# Javascript for loop not waiting for .then to finish

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I have the following code to retrieve some file information from Firebase:

```
function loadUserProfileKeys(key) {
  // Get the Firebase storage ref for the InitialUserProfiles folder
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
  var initialUserProfilesRef = storageRef.child('InitialUserProfiles'); // .txt files folder

  // Array
  const keyResults = [];

  // Retrieve all profiles
  initialUserProfilesRef.listAll()
    .then(function(res) {

      // Loop over each item
      for (const itemRef of res.items) {
        console.log("Start for loop");

        // Ignore profiles with symbols (workaround - TODO: fix this)
        if (/,|&/.test(itemRef.name)) {} else {
          // Path of the file
          var pathRef = initialUserProfilesRef.child(itemRef.name);

          // Get the file's download URL
          var downloadURL = pathRef.getDownloadURL()
            .then((url) => {

              // Get the given key from the user profile text file
              getValueKey(url, key)
                .then((value) => {
                  // Add it to the keyResults array
                  keyResults.push(value);
                });
            });
        }
      }
      console.log("End for loop");
      console.log(keyResults);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log("ERROR");
      console.log(error);
    });
}

async function getValueKey(fileURL, key) {
  let response = await fetch(fileURL);

  if (response.status == 200) {
    let json = await response.text(); // (3)
    var lines = json.split("\n");
    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      var line = lines[i];
      var pairs = line.split(":");
      if (pairs.length == 2 && pairs[0].trim() == key) {
        results.push(pairs[1].trim());
      }
    }
    return Promise.resolve(results[0]);
  }
}
```

The logging itself is fine - it won't log "End for loop" until all of the looping, i.e. multiple "Start for loop" logs, is done.
The issue is that this is still *before* `keyResults.push(value);` is called - and thus the array is empty (or very occasionally only partly populated).

How do I get `var downloadURL = pathRef.getDownloadURL()` and `getValueKey(url, key)` to be blocking - so that it does not iterate over the loop until the nested `.then((value)` is called to add to the array?

I can't figure out async etc - I keep getting syntax errors.

---

```
function loadUserProfileKeys(key) {
  // Get the Firebase storage ref for the InitialUserProfiles folder
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
  var initialUserProfilesRef = storageRef.child('InitialUserProfiles'); // .txt files folder

  const keyResults = Promise.all(initialUserProfilesRef.listAll().then(function(res) {
    // Loop over each item
    return res.items.map((itemRef) => {
      // Ignore profiles with symbols (workaround - TODO: fix this)
      if (/,|&/.test(itemRef.name)) {} else {
        // Path of the file
        var pathRef = initialUserProfilesRef.child(itemRef.name);

        // Get the file's download URL
        return pathRef.getDownloadURL()
          .then((url) => {
            // Get the given key from the user profile text file
            return getValueKey(url, key)
          });
      };
    });
  }));
  console.log("End for loop");
  console.log(keyResults);
}

async function getValueKey(fileURL, key) {
  let response = await fetch(fileURL);

  if (response.status == 200) {
    let json = await response.text(); // (3)
    var lines = json.split("\n");
    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      var line = lines[i];
      var pairs = line.split(":");
      if (pairs.length == 2 && pairs[0].trim() == key) {
        results.push(pairs[1].trim());
      }
    }
    return Promise.resolve(results[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no way to make promises blocking. You'll probably have to use callbacks.

Comment: I know nothing about firebase but perhaps an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to wait for multiple asynchronous operations to all be finished, you'll want to use `Promise.all()`.

Something like this should be getting a lot closer:

```js
return initialUserProfilesRef.listAll()
  .then((res) => {
    return Promise.all(
      res.items.map((itemRef) => { // Loop over each item
        // Ignore profiles with symbols (workaround - TODO: fix this)
        if (/,|&/.test(itemRef.name)) {
          // you might want to return something here, e.g.
          return { skipped: true }
        } else {
          // Path of the file
          var pathRef = initialUserProfilesRef.child(itemRef.name);

          // Get the file's download URL
          return pathRef.getDownloadURL()
            .then((url) => {
              // Get the given key from the user profile text file
              return getValueKey(url, key)
            });
        }
      })
    );
  })
  .then((keyResults) => {
    console.log("End for loop");
    console.log(keyResults);
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I've edited the question with my attempt at using your suggestion. I'm now getting `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Argument of Promise.all is not iterable`.

Comment: @SwiftBehemoth This approach originally handed `Promise.all()` a `Promise<Promise[]>` instead of the `Promise[]` itself which has now been corrected. If you make `loadUserProfileKeys` `async`, you can further simplify it.

Comment: Thanks for fixing that Sam!  I'd been staring at it for a while, but didn't see my mistake.

Comment: Thank you both so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would make `loadUserProfileKeys` a async function.

That way you can simply await your other async functions (`pathRef.getDownloadURL()`, `getValueKey(url, key)`).

Here is your Snipped modified using async & await.
I did not test it, but it should work.

```js
async function loadUserProfileKeys(key) {
  // Get the Firebase storage ref for the InitialUserProfiles folder
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
  var initialUserProfilesRef = storageRef.child('InitialUserProfiles'); // .txt files folder

  // Array
  const keyResults = [];

  try {
    // Retrieve all profiles
    const profileRes = await initialUserProfilesRef.listAll();

    // Loop over each item
    for (const itemRef of profileRes.items) {
      console.log("Start for loop");

      // Ignore profiles with symbols (workaround - TODO: fix this)
      if (/,|&/.test(itemRef.name)) {} else {
        // Path of the file
        var pathRef = initialUserProfilesRef.child(itemRef.name);

        // Get the file's download URL
        var downloadURL = await pathRef.getDownloadURL();

        // Get the given key from the user profile text file
        keyResults.push(await getValueKey(downloadURL, key));
      }
    }
    console.log("End for loop");
    console.log(keyResults);
  } catch(error) {
    console.log("ERROR");
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

In general i would personally recommend try to avoid encapsulating .then() calls.

It just makes the code harder to read and understand.

I find async & await much cleaner.

Comment: Warning: While this approach would work, this answer processes each item one-by-one. With the time that `getDownloadURL()` takes to resolve, a parallel approach should be used instead.

Comment: @samthecodingman this is true. As additional optimization you could replace the for loop with a .map() call on the items.
Those map calls should return a Promise.
And using Promise.all() to process them in parallel

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
async function loadUserProfileKeys(key) {
    // Get the Firebase storage ref for the InitialUserProfiles folder
    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    var initialUserProfilesRef = storageRef.child('InitialUserProfiles'); // .txt files folder

    // Array
    const keyResults = [];

    // Retrieve all profiles
    const res = await initialUserProfilesRef.listAll();

    // Loop over each items
    res.items.forEach(async (itemRef) => {
        console.log("Start for loop");

        // Ignore profiles with symbols (workaround - TODO: fix this)
        if (/,|&/.test(itemRef.name)) {
            // skip
        } else {
            // Path of the file
            const pathRef = initialUserProfilesRef.child(itemRef.name);

            // Get the file's download URL
            const url = await pathRef.getDownloadURL();
            
            // Get the given key from the user profile text file
            const value = await getValueKey(url, key);
            .
            // Add it to the keyResults array
            keyResults.push(value);
        }
    });
    console.log("End for loop");
    console.log(keyResults);
}

async function getValueKey(fileURL, key) {
    let response = await fetch(fileURL);

    if (response.status == 200) {
        let json = await response.text(); // (3)
        var lines = json.split("\n");
        var results = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            var line = lines[i];
            var pairs = line.split(":");
            if (pairs.length == 2 && pairs[0].trim() == key) {
                results.push(pairs[1].trim());
            }
        }
        return Promise.resolve(results[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Warning: As written, this answer does not correctly wait for each Promise to resolve before returning the results and thus does not answer the question.

Comment: @samthecodingman Are you sure? I don't think so..... it will wait for each promise to resolve. You should provide the reason that where it will fail into code before directly saying it that it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

So to add - this works as expected but probably isn't optimum + could maybe be tidied a little:

```
async function loadUserProfileKeys(key) {
  // Get the Firebase storage ref for the InitialUserProfiles folder
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
  var initialUserProfilesRef = storageRef.child('InitialUserProfiles'); // .txt files folder

  // Results array
  var keyResults = [];

  // Retrieve all profiles
  const profiles = await initialUserProfilesRef.listAll()

  var promises = [];

  // Loop over each file
  for (const itemRef of profiles.items) {
    console.log("Start for loop");

    // Ignore profiles with symbols (workaround - TODO: fix this)
    if (/,|&/.test(itemRef.name)) {} else {
      // Path of the file
      var pathRef = initialUserProfilesRef.child(itemRef.name);

      // Add to the array of Promises
      promises.push(doSomething(pathRef, key));
    };
  };

  // Wait for all Promises to resolve
  keyResults = await Promise.all(promises)

  console.log("End for loop");
  console.log(keyResults);
}

async function doSomething(pathRef, key) {
  var downloadURL = await pathRef.getDownloadURL();
  var value = await getValueKey(downloadURL, key);
  return value
}

async function getValueKey(fileURL, key) {
  let response = await fetch(fileURL);

  if (response.status == 200) {
    let json = await response.text(); // (3)
    var lines = json.split("\n");
    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      var line = lines[i];
      var pairs = line.split(":");
      if (pairs.length == 2 && pairs[0].trim() == key) {
        results.push(pairs[1].trim());
      }
    }
    return results[0];
  }
}
```